# How do I render a dropdown list in a Django Template?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Stack Overflow so forgive me if I don't get everything correct on the first try. I'm also new to Django and I'm having trouble understanding how to render a dropdown list on an html template. I took a look at a few other solutions here, but I think they may be a bit outdated. If you're able to help or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Here is my model.py:

```
class Food(models.Model):

    FRUIT = (('1', 'Apples'),('2','Oranges'),('3','Pears'),('4','Grapes'))
    Fruit= models.CharField(max_length= 42, choices=FRUIT)

    VEGETABLES = (('1', 'Carrots'),('2','Celery'),('3','Beets'),('4','Onions'))
    Vegetables= models.CharField(max_length= 42, choices=VEGETABLES)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
from models import Food

@login_required(login_url = 'signin')
def Page3(request):
    foods = Food.objects.all()
    return render(request,'Page3.html',{"foods":foods})
```

Here is the HTML snippet that I want the dropdown to show up in:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="{{Food.fruits}}">1. What is your favorite fruit?</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="Q1">
        <option disabled = "true" selected>Select</option>
        {% for food in foods %}
        <option value = "{{foods.fruit}}">{{foods.fruit}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
```

When I execute this code, I only see the disabled "Select" option and "1". I tried to follow these solutions here but to no avail.

[Django Templates and drop-down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155743/django-templates-and-drop-down-list)

[How to add display dropdown fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62839945/how-to-add-display-dropdown-fields-in-django)

Thanks again, and let me know if there's anything that I'm missing that could help answer this questions better.

Comment: Why not just use a django form?

Comment: I didn't realize I could use  a django form instead. I've been taking a course and it wasn't mentioned. But I'll look into that. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, just create a form with a choice field and in the form `__init__` load the choices from `Food.objects.all()`